# Adding config file for Cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell, appfabric, powershell-cmdlet

I've made a powershell Cmdlet for creating an AppFabric a region, the code:

```
    [Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.New, "CacheRegion")]

public class NewCacheRegion : Cmdlet {
    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 1)]
    public string Cache { get; set; }

    [Parameter(Mandatory = true, Position = 2)]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord() {
        base.ProcessRecord();

        DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory(); // exception

        DataCache cache = factory.GetCache(Cache);

        try {
            cache.CreateRegion(Region);
        }
        catch (DataCacheException ex) {}
    }
}
```

It's installed with import-module appfabriccmdlet.dll and the code executes when running new-cacheregion.

**but** the line

```
DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory();
```

throws an exception that server collection is empty which means that no dataCacheClient section is found in app.config. So I want to a client that but Im not sure in which config file to add the appfabric sections. I've tried finding out from what executable the cmdlet dll is running with

```
Assembly a = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```

but that returns null.

So where do I need to put config sections that a cmdlet dll has access to?

Answer (score 0):

never mind.

fixed it by programmatically adding the server without config

```
        DataCacheServerEndpoint[] servers = new DataCacheServerEndpoint[1];
        servers[0] = new DataCacheServerEndpoint("localhost", 22233);

        DataCacheFactoryConfiguration conf = new DataCacheFactoryConfiguration();

        conf.Servers = servers;

        DataCacheFactory factory = new DataCacheFactory(conf);
```